# Cannot set HTML5 <Audio> Volume in Android 4 Browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-audio

i have a web app that play audio files using  tag, in Android 4.0.3 browser it seems that i'm unable to set the volume. Also the volume control doesn't show at all.

Anyone knows if this is a bug or something else?

The application works just fine on desktop chrome/firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Android's Ice Cream Sandwich. The getters/setters work if you check the values but the physical volume never gets set. Feel free to enter this bug into their dev network.