# HTML5 Audio Mute in Android webview

Tags: java, android, jquery-mobile, android-webview, html5-audio

I am using HTML5 audio player inside an android webview. I want to mute the audio and I am using the code like this

```
        this.mute = function()
        {
            console.debug("Muted");
            if(_audioHtml.muted == undefined) {
                alert("Doesn't exist");
            }
            else {
                if(_audioHtml.muted === true) {
                    alert("Muted");
                }
                else if (_audioHtml.muted === false) {
                    alert("Non Muted");
                }
                else {
                    alert("None of them");   
                }
            }
            _audioHtml.muted = true;
        };
```

After each call I can see that the value of muted changes. But its not generating any effect on the device.  It always generate the sound in set volume. How can I do this in android. I am using Android 4.0.4.

Thanks.

Comment: I found the same issue in my app.
Tested Devices : 
Samsung galaxy S3,
Nexus (ICS, JB),
HTC 1S

Comment: Anyone have any ideas for work-arounds?

Comment: Is there equivalent code you could test in a desktop browser, so you can rule out whether it's android or the code?  Is your code HTML5 specific, and does the device you're using explicitly support the HTML5 features you're trying to use?

Comment: What is `_audioHtml` in your code? Is it the `<audio>` tag itself, or the entire document?

Comment: Maybe just turn the volume to 0 and block the call with a boolean?

Comment: Yes joequincy, _audioHtml is the audio tag itself

Comment: I have also tried to set the volume to 0.0 but it's not better... See also this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221822/cannot-set-html5-audio-volume-in-android-4-browser)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an audio tag like `<audio id="player" src="something.mp3" />`, you should be toggling the `muted` property of the tag itself using Javascript... something like

```
$('#player').muted = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

It works if you set the audio this way: (the  html5 tag will be muted)
In your JAVA activity:

```
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");     
 wv.addJavascriptInterface(this, "jInterface");
```

in your html file:
to mute:

```
<script>
jInterface.mute();
</script>
```

now back to your java activity:

```
public void mute()
        {
             audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution for my MotoX 4.2 device yet, but this tends to work in most cases, basically you have pause the video once it starts playing

The caveat here is that my Samsung 4.3 device is firing "playing" way too early, it should fire when the video actually starts playing, but it fires when the video starts loading

```
if (sdkVersion < 4.4) {
    player.addEventListener("timeupdate", pauseIfPlaying); // check player.currentTime > 0
} else {
    player.addEventListener("playing", function () {
        player.muted = true;
    });
}
```