# Mute webview audio without javascript injection

Tags: android, android-webview, html5-audio

I would like to disable sound in a webview element of my app.

How can I achieve this without injecting javascript in the webpage?

I don't have control over the content of the content displayed.

I am aware of similar questions:

[Mute webview in android apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676323/mute-webview-in-android-apps)

[HTML5 Audio Mute in Android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568304/html5-audio-mute-in-android-webview)

They don't have constraint of no javascript injection, hence I have added a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can not mute only WebView but you can mute all app volume with AudioManager.

And here is the solution : [Mute webview in android apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676323/mute-webview-in-android-apps)

Javascript is not used in these solutions, and I don't think there is any other way, you have no chance to interfere with the webview.

Comment: Disabling sound system-wide is not what I am looking for. I have other components in my app, which play sound.

Comment: While WebView is playing audio, is there another view playing audio?

Comment: Yes I have another view playing audio simultaneously .